# Scala: perform multiple maps and flatmaps on a set of strings

Tags: scala

I'm pretty new to scala (and programming in general), but have come up with what feels like a less than perfect solution to an issue I have - I was wondering if anyone has a more elegant/efficient one?

I have a (very large) set of strings, a small example of which is below for replication purposes:

```
val brands = Set("Brand one", "BRAND-two!!!", "brand_Three1, brandThree2", "brand04")
```

Now what I want to do is clean up this set so that I have a new clean set where:

1. any strings separated by commas are split into separate strings
2. leading spaces and non-alphanumeric (and _ -) characters are
   removed
3. any string with a space is replaced by three version of
   that string (one with no space, one with "-" instead of a space, and one and one with "_")

The code I have so far does this, but it does it in two steps, thus iterating over the list twice (which is inefficient):

```
   val brands_clean = brands.flatMap(
      _.toLowerCase.split(",").map(
        _.trim.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9\\-\\_\\s]+", "")
      )
    )

    def spaceVariations(v: String) = if (v.contains(" ")) Set(v.replaceAll(" ", "-"), v.replaceAll(" ", "_"), v.replaceAll(" ", "")) else Set(v)

    val brands_final = brands_clean.flatMap(spaceVariations(_))
```

I have tried incorporating the spaceVariations function directly into the main code by appending to the replaceAll a map or flatMap:

```
// using the function call
.flatMap(spaceVariations(_))   

// or using a function directly within the code
.flatMap {v => if (v.contains(" ")) Set(v.replaceAll(" ", "-"), v.replaceAll(" ", "_"), v.replaceAll(" ", "")) else Set(v) }
```

but I get the following error:

```
 error: type mismatch;
 found   : Array[Nothing]
 required: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]
```

I'm not sure I understand why this doesn't work here, or if there is a better way to achieve what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  brands.flatMap(
    _.toLowerCase.split(",").map(
      _.trim.replaceAll("""[^\w-]""", "")
    )
  ).flatMap(spaceVariations)
```

Works for me, not sure where (or why) you are getting the error (I cleaned up your regex a little bit to make it more concise, but that shouldn't matter).

Note, that this *still* traverses the set twice though. Sets are not lazy in scala, so, it will complete the first `flatMap` with an intermediate set first, and then start with the next one.

If you want to save a scan, you should starts with an `Iterator` rather than a set, because iterators are lazy, and will send each element through the whole chain before moving on to the next one:

```
brands
 .iterator
 .flatMap { _.toLowerCase.split(",") }
 .map(_.trim)
 .map { _.replaceAll("""[^\w-]""", "") }
 .flatMap(spaceVariations)
 .toSet
```

Comment: Hi again @Dima. This doesn't seem to apply the spaceVariation function, i.e. the output does not have the three variations of the string with spaces in it. But i like the idea of using the iterator!

Comment: @renegademonkey
That's because your `_.replaceAll` thingy removes all the spaces ;)

Comment: I just realised that last night too . . .  however, that was due to your 'improved' replaceAll - my original replaceAll was `"[^A-Za-z0-9\-\_\s]+"` , which kept the spaces ;-) . Changed it back - works great now! Many thanks - especially for the iterator tip.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I missed `\s` in your original. Sorry about that.  `"""[^\s\w-]"""` should work (the whole point of writing it more concisely is that people don't miss parts of it among all the slashes and dashes).

Comment: Oooooh, I also just figured out what the triple quotes mean - that is SUPER useful. I've had to do huge regex's in Java before and found myself in backslash hell. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the assumption that your `Set` will always look like this:

```
def spaceVariations(v: String) = if (v.contains(" ")) Set(v.replaceAll(" ", "-"), v.replaceAll(" ", "_"), v.replaceAll(" ", "")) else Set(v)

 val brands = Set("Brand one", "BRAND-two!!!", "brand_Three1, brandThree2", "brand04")

brands.map( x => if (x.contains(",") ) x.split(",") else x ).flatMap {
    case str: String => Array(str)
    case a : Array[String] => a 
}.map(_.trim.toLowerCase.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9\\-\\_\\s]+", "")).map(spaceVariations(_))
```

Gives the output :

```
Set(Set(brand-one, brand_one, brandone), Set(brandthree2), Set(brand04), Set(brand-two), Set(brand_three1))
```

Comment: the goal is to have a final completely flat `Set` with just strings (i.e. no substrings), is that possible to do that all in one go efficiently?

Comment: perform a `flatMap(identity)` after the last operation.

Comment: i do realise that, but can it be done within the main set of instructions?

Comment: Which set of operations? You can just add `.flatMap(identity)` after the last map `.map(spaceVariations(_))`

Comment: oooooh OK, that totally works! What is `identity` exactly?

Comment: a nice looking `flatMap(x => x)`